# Can You Use GSAP Draggable with PIXI.Graphics?

Tags: draggable, gsap, pixi.js

I am creating a circle with `PIXI.Graphics` and then trying to use `Draggable` to move the circle on the X axis.
The error i get is:

> Uncaught Cannot tween a null target.

I have set the graphics object's interactive property to true...

Is this because `Draggable` does not work with `PIXI.Graphics` or I have made another mistake?

Here is the code where i create the graphics object in a class extending PIXI.Graphics:

```
export default class BlueDot extends PIXI.Graphics {
constructor(x, y) {
    super()
    this._init()
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.interactive = true;
    this.buttonMode = true;
    this.dragDot();


}
_init() {
    this.lineStyle(0)
    this.pivot.set(this.x, this.y)
    this.beginFill(0x55f, 1)
    this.drawCircle(this.x, this.y, 20)
    this.endFill()
    this.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(this.x, this.y, 20)
}
dragDot() {
  Draggable.create(this, {
      type: 'x, y',
  })
}
```

Then i add an instance of this class in another class.

Comment: This is definitely possible! However, it is impossible for us to help find the error since you don't provide code to reproduce the error. Can you please create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include it in your question?

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kristianzanev was right, Draggable only works with DOM objects. So can either wrap your Pixi object in a DOM object and drag that around or use a proxy object.

To use a proxy, you can create it like so:

```
var proxy = document.createElement("div");

var draggable = new Draggable(proxy, {
  trigger: canvas,
  bounds: canvas,
  cursor: "inherit",
  throwProps: true,
  onPress: pressAction,
  onDrag: moveAction,
  onThrowUpdate: moveAction
}).disable();
```

And then use the press, move, and throw update to update your Pixi object. [Demo](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/50e73afa5b9cd1f7141695524da09df4).

For more information, check out the [GreenSock forum thread](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/15789-can-you-use-draggable-with-pixijs/) on the same topic.

Comment: Great. This works! I also managed to do the job by using event listeners on the PIXI.Graphics object, but using Draggable is better in terms of user experience and performance.